# Tizen Web/native app form validation

Tags: tizen

I was searching for Tizen form validation tutorial in both web and native app. I found nothing about these in popular libraries like jQuery/Angular JS.

I found this https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/using-livevalidation-javascript-library

Comment: Did you try HTML5 default attributes ?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: yss got it ...thanks anywy

Comment: i know these but i though tizen have its own api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any available form validation plugins uing Jquery/AngularJS which are application for hosted Web Application. For example, i am using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Just follow 2mins tutorial from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/).

I have adjusted the form in Tizen UI.

```
<div id="main" class="page">
         <div class="contents">
          <div class="container">
             <form action="" name="registration">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Steave"/>

                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Smith"/>

                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="xyz@s.com"/>

                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;"/>

                <button type="submit">Register</button>
             </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Required libraries and js must be added.

```
  <script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/form-validation.js"></script>
```

[image]